# Prerequisites for High Dimensional Geometry

Tags: soft-question

I found the follwing (below) PDFs and was wondering what I need to know (other than Linear Algebra and Probability) before reading them.

Usually when I need to quicky learn about a subject I go to Amazon and check out the TOC of relevant books, but in this case High Dimensional Geo turns up nothing. Is it a subset of (possibly more general) subject? Does this subject possibly go by any other names?

http://circuit.ucsd.edu/~massimo/ECE287C/Handouts_files/Geometry.pdf

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/chap1-high-dim-space.pdf